# Show that $\int_a^be^{tf(x)}\text{d}x \underset{}{\sim} \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}e^{tf(x)}\text{d}x$ under an hypothesis.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $a < b$, and let $f : [a, b] \mapsto \mathbb R$, $f \in C^\infty[a,b]$.

Suppose there exists a unique point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ where $f$ reaches its maximum, we have $a < x_0 < b$, $f''(x_0)\ne0$.

1. Show that we have $f''(x_0) < 0$.
2. Show that for all $\delta > 0$ such as $\delta < \min(x_0-a, b - x_0)$, we have, as $t \to \infty$

$$\int_a^be^{tf(x)}\text{d}x \underset{}{\sim} \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}e^{tf(x)}\text{d}x.$$

I did question 1. quite easily but I would need some help for question 2.

It tried solving this problem by splitting the integral $\displaystyle{\int_a^be^{tf(x)}\text{d}x}$ in the three following integrals : $\displaystyle{\int_a^{x_0-\delta}e^{tf(x)}\text{d}x}$, $\displaystyle{\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}e^{tf(x)}\text{d}x}$, $\displaystyle{\int_{x_0+\delta}^be^{tf(x)}\text{d}x}$ and then I tried showing the left and right integrals tend to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: This looks like Laplace's method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). some terms seem to be missing in your asymptotics.

Comment: The left and the right integrals do not necessarily tend to 0, you need to show that their values are *much* smaller than the middle integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M := f(x_0)$ and given any such $\delta$ as in your statement, since $x_0$ is the unique point where the maximum is attained, there exists $\epsilon >0$ small enough such that on $[a,b]\setminus(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, we have $f \leq (M-\epsilon)$. Then,
$$
\int_{[a,b]\setminus(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} e^{tf(x)}dx \leq (b-a) e^{t(M-\epsilon)}.
$$
By continuity, we can find $\eta >0$ small enough such that $(x_0 -\eta, x_0 + \eta) \subset (x_0 -\delta, x_0 + \delta)$ and on $(x_0 -\eta, x_0 + \eta)$, we have $f \geq M-(\epsilon/2)$. Then we get
$$
\int_{(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} e^{tf(x)}dx \geq \int_{(x_0 - \eta, x_0 + \eta)} e^{tf(x)}dx \geq 2\eta e^{t(M-(\epsilon/2))}.
$$
Hence as $t \rightarrow \infty$, (since $M-(\epsilon/2) > M-\epsilon$) we can conclude that
$$
\int_{(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} e^{tf(x)}dx \gg \int_{[a,b]\setminus(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} e^{tf(x)}dx,
$$
and the required result then follows.